# Custom Sanitation Function Triggering an Alert in Customizer?

Tags: theme-customizer, callbacks

I have an image upload field in theme-customizer :

```
/* Background Image */
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'tcx_background_image',
    array(
        'default'      => '',
        'transport'    => 'postMessage',
        'sanitize_callback'  => 'is_image',
    )
);
```

And sanitize-callback function :

```
function is_image( $input ) {
if(getimagesize($input)){   
    return esc_url_raw($input);     
}else{
        return '';  
     }
}
```

This part works correctly :

I click **Select Image** button and then I select my image inside **Media Library** and I click **Choose Image** and finally i click **Save&Publish** and my image is outputted correctly (Nothing wrong thus far)

Here is the dreaded **alert problem** ( Happens when clicking **X** button in Customizer ):

Now I want to **Remove** my image so I click **Remove** button and now there is no image, then I click **Save&Publish** button.

The problem arises when I click **X** (EXIT) button inside Customizer because it triggers an alert box 
"The changes you made will be lost if you navigate away from this page.Are you sure you want to leave this page?".

I have enabled `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` if set it to false the alert is gone,also if I set my `'sanitize_callback'  => 'esc_url_raw',` the alert is also gone it happens only if I use my custom function `is_image();`

**So how can I remove that alert box when using custom function?**

This is js file for customize-preview if that helps... THX!!

```
wp.customize( 'tcx_background_image', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {

        0 === $.trim( to ).length ?
            $( 'body' ).css( 'background-image', '' ) :
            $( 'body' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + to + ')' );

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it looks like that `getimagesize` will generate error/notice if image is not found, so alert box will fire...

This is straight from PHP docs:

If accessing the filename image is impossible getimagesize() will generate an error of level E_WARNING. On read error, getimagesize() will generate an error of level E_NOTICE.

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
function is_image( $input ) {
   if ( !empty($input) && getimagesize($input)) {
     return esc_url_raw($input);
   } else {
    return '';
   }
}
```

If somebody has a better solution please let me know...